# VB.Net BalloonTipText appears as a black rectangle

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I have a strange problem, I have created a test form `FrmTest`. Added a NotifyIcon and added the code shown:

```
Public Class FrmTest
    Private Sub FrmTest_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Sub FormTest_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        Call SetBalloonTip()
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000)    
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetBalloonTip()
        NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Balloon Tip Title"
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Balloon Tip Text."
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error    
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click to make the balloon appear I get this:

[image: Balloon Pic]

I must be doing something obviously wrong but I am stumped!

Comment: That is what a balloon looks like on Win10.  Nothing is wrong.

Comment: Oh, that's a surprise! OK Thankyou.

Comment: How do I mark as answered, I don't see the green tick?

Comment: There isn't one because an answer has not been posted. There is already four close votes on the question, so just one more and it will be taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to say you did well...
That is what a balloon Tip looks like on Windows 10. Best of luck.